# how to number recycleView elements

Tags: android-recyclerview

How can I number my elements in the RecycleView? I want my elements to be numbered when added as by index, and so that when deleted I can have its number as a position and when deleted the number of the rest is shifted too

For example:

I have 3 elements:

0. test

1.test1

2.test2

and so that when I deleted test1 it became:

0. test

1. test2

and so that I can also write this into the database,

Here is the RecycleView Adapter code

```
<pre><code>
import android.view.LayoutInflater 
import android.view.View 
import android.view.ViewGroup 
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
import com.example.myappplan.R import com.example.myappplan.databinding.PlansItemBinding 

      
class PlansAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<PlansAdapter.PlansHolder>() {val planlist = ArrayList<Plans>()class PlansHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {val binding = PlansItemBinding.bind(item)var number_plans = 0fun bind(plans: Plans) = with(binding){textTitle.text = plans.titletextInfo.text = plans.discritpiontextTimeInfo.text = plans.time 
numberPlans.text = number_plans.toString() + "."

        when ("") {
            plans.title -> {
                textTitle.text = "None"
                when("") {
                    plans.discritpion -> {
                        textInfo.visibility = View.GONE
                        when ("Не назначено") {
                            plans.time -> textTimeInfo.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                    }

                else -> {
                    textInfo.visibility= View.VISIBLE
                    textTimeInfo.visibility= View.VISIBLE }

                }
            }
            plans.discritpion -> {
                textInfo.visibility = View.GONE
                when ("Не назначено") {
                    plans.time -> textTimeInfo.visibility = View.GONE
                    else -> textTimeInfo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }

            else -> {
                textInfo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                when ("Не назначено") {
                    plans.time -> textTimeInfo.visibility = View.GONE
                    else -> textTimeInfo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PlansHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.plans_item, parent, false)
    return PlansHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PlansHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(planlist[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return planlist.size
}

fun addPlans(plans: Plans){
    planlist.add(plans)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
</code></pre>
```

here is the code that passes the data to create the element:

```
<pre><code>
fun bDone_Correct_Date() = with(binding){
    val plans = Plans(timeInfo.text.toString(),edTitle.text.toString(), edDisc.text.toString())
    val editIntent = Intent().apply {
        putExtra("plans", plans)
    }
    setResult(RESULT_OK, editIntent)
    finish()
</code></pre>
```

And I wanted to know how to better work with the database,

I have a database

where there are columns with id, Data, numer, title, description, time

and let’s say I need all the elements from the database with data = 07/2/2023

and so that they are loaded sequentially in accordance with number, what is the best way to do it, select these lines through a search (if possible), or create a separate database for each date and do the sequence by id?

I hope I explained everything clearly, if you need additional data, write the code, I will send everything, I hope my problem can be solved